# How do I create a command to make me stay at one stack of an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to make a command that keeps me at one stack of arrows.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this for a map? Creative mode? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4):

### 1. CommandStats

Using CommandStats allows you to detect the number of specific items in a player's inventory no matter how they are arranged. This both allows you to accurately provide arrows until they reach exactly 64 as well as remove arrows if they have more than 64.

#### Prerequisites

Objective to hold the number of relevant items.

```
/scoreboard objectives add ArrowCount dummy
```

"AffectedItems" CommandStat trigger to apply to players, who will target their own "ArrowCount" score. This may need to run on a clock if new players may join at any time.

```
/stats entity @a set AffectedItems @a[c=1] ArrowCount
```

In order for CommandStats to modify a target's score, that target must be tracked prior. This may also need to run on a clock for the same reason.

```
/scoreboard players add @a ArrowCount 0
```

#### Clock commands

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Cause players to run a `/clear` command that looks for a specific item. The maximum amount is set to 0, which means no items will be removed but the "AffectedItems" trigger will be sent the total number of that item the player has in their inventory. You can add to this command to look for an exact arrow rather than generic arrows.

   ```
   /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /clear @a[c=1] minecraft:arrow 0 0
   ```
2. Players that have 63 or fewer arrows will be given a new arrow.

   ```
   /give @a[score_ArrowCount=63] minecraft:arrow
   ```
3. Players with 65 or more arrows will have the extra arrows removed.

   ```
   /clear @a[score_ArrowCount_min=65] minecraft:arrow 0 1
   ```

The final result is the player never having more or less than 64 of that specific arrow in their inventory.

### 2. Statistics

The `stat.useItem.bow` objective-type will increase when the bow is used, and you can use that to provide the player with the appropriate number of arrows.

```
/scoreboard objectives add UseBow stat.useItem.minecraft.bow
```

And the following would run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Provide relevant players with an arrow after they have used their bow.

   ```
   /give @a[score_UseBow_min=1] minecraft:arrow
   ```
2. Reduce their "UseBow" score by 1.

   ```
   /scoreboard players remove @a[score_UseBow_min=1] UseBow 1
   ```

The downside is you will not be able to differentiate between special arrows that have been removed, such as tipped arrows, and normal arrows. As well, the player can pick up more than the allotted 64 arrows since this only provides new arrows rather than removing extra.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put the following commands in a repeat/chain command block line:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=arrows] remove arrows
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!arrows] add arrows {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:arrow,Count:63}]}
/give @a[tag=arrows] minecraft:arrow
```

Note that you must start off with either 63 or 64 arrows for this command to work.

[image: When you fire an arrow, it is instantly replaced.]

Comment: Be aware that this requires all arrows to be within the same stack. If the player spreads the arrows out in such a manner that they will never have exactly 63 in a stack, the mechanism will fail.

Comment: @Skylinerw The question said `keep me at **one** stack of arrows` so I assumed that they would all be in the same stack.

Answer (score 1):

Set a command block to (clock)

```
testfor @e[type=arrow,r=radiusInBlocks]
```

then have a comparator going out of it connecting to two command blocks (needs redstone) with

```
give player minecraft:arrow
```

and after some delay...

> kill @e[type=arrow]

Then if you start with 64 arrows, you shoot one, you gain one! :D

Comment: This solution does not work at all with multiplayer, or when you expect another user is going to use your map.

Comment: Also, this won't work for more arrows shot!

Comment: Sorry let me edit this...